# Consulta distinta para uma mesma coluna

Tags: wordpress, query, mysqli

Estou com uma query que faz a filtragem por tipo de impressão e tipo de formato, o problema que ambos os tipos usam a mesma coluna  "meta_value" para registrar os valores.

Exemplo do que preciso:

Ao usuário marcar Tipo de impressão "colorido" e tipo de formato "A3" preciso que o sistema traga todas as impressoras coloridas com o formato A3 somente.
Tentei usar Case mas o resultado não é satisfatório, segue onde parei:

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (p.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE p.post_type =  'equipamentos'
    AND p.post_status =  'publish'
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'categorias'  
    and wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 322 
    -- a treta está aqui
    and (
            (meta_value = 'Colorido' and meta_key = 'tipo_impressao')
        or  (meta_value = 'A4' and meta_key = 'formato')
    )
    order by p.post_date asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom consegui encontrar uma solução.
A utilização de left join na situação informada retorna dois registros duplicados no caso do wordpress, por isso que o resultado não está sendo filtrado corretamente, então para marcação multipla de filtragem como sugerido introduzi:

```
having count(*) > 1
```

E desta forma para este tipo de segmentação o sistema só trará somente os registros duplicados e utilizei group by para agrupar os ids duplicados e ter os registros dividamente filtrados:

```
...
group by ID 
    having count(*) > 1
    order by p.post_date asc
```